# Solving for the parametrization

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametric, line-integrals

I was wondering when evaluating line curves, and C is given by something such as $y = x^2$, how do you find the parametrization $<t, t^2, 0>$ ? ( I understand how z was found but not so much x and y; like what is the actual algebra?)

When it comes to parametrization along a line (from a single point to another single point) I can find $r(t)$, but not so much when given an equation such as that one.

Comment: For every $y=f(x)$, there is always the trivial $x=t$, $y=f(t)$...

Comment: For $y=x^2$ the parametric form is simply $t,t^2$ , by assuming x is dependant on variable t and finding y in terms of t using given condition.

Comment: Won't $t\mapsto (t,t^2)$ do the job?